# I am trying to send File as a parameter to a method but dont know how?

Tags: java, file, exception, java.util.scanner, reader

```
public static void createFile() {

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\egecoskun\\Desktop\\javafiles\\ananınamı.txt");
    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("Dosya olusturuldu!");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Dosya zaten var!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here is my createFile method to create a file.

```
public static void readFile(File file) {
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String line=reader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and this method is reading the file i am creating.But it needs to take File as an argument but when i try to run this method in Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    createFile();
    readFile(file);

}
```

The error i am getting is file cannot be resolved to a variable.
Does anyone spot my mistake? Can you explain it please.

Comment: create file object from createFile method and pass it into the read method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return file object from createFile Function and pass it to readFile Function

```
public static File createFile() {
    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\egecoskun\\Desktop\\javafiles");
    if(dir.exists()) {
       dir.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(dir,"ananınamı.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
    return file;
}
```

In your main function

```
File file = createFile();
readFile(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

`createFile` is `void`; that means it does not return anything. In this case, you want to return a `File`. Like,

```
public static File createFile() {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\egecoskun\\Desktop\\javafiles\\ananınamı.txt");
    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("Dosya olusturuldu!");
            return file;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dosya zaten var!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you need to assign the result of calling that method to a variable. And you should check that it is not `null` before you pass it to `readFile`. Like,

```
File f = createFile();
if (f != null) {
    readFile(f);
}
```

Note that the file won't actually contain anything to read. It just exists after you created it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Elliott but do i need to return null that confused me a little?

Comment: Yes you have to return null in case if the dir does not exist or may be you can check if the dir does not exists you can create new dir and remove the try catch statement

Comment: Please don't teach newbies deplorable java code style. 'print the stack trace and return null' is a crazy way to deal with IOExceptions in this code. This method should be declared to `throws IOException`, because the signature of the method itself (its name, arguments, return type, and javadoc) inherently implies I/O is occurring (IOException is therefore not an implementation detail but inherent in its very nature). the `psv main` method should, as just about all `main` methods should, be declared to `throws Exception`. Less code, better code, cleaner code, better behaviour. Win-win-win-win.

Comment: @rzwitserloot That code is in the question, and I still don't see the point in reading an empty file.

Comment: I am not reading an empty file.I also have a writeFile method which you cant see @ElliottFrisch.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCall2 {
    public static void CALL(FileOutputStream fr, int w) {
       try {
         fr.write(w);
       } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
       }
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     try (FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("c:\\code\\a.txt")) {
        FileOutputStream f2 = new FileOutputStream("c:\\code\\a2.txt");
      int c;
      char wd;
      while((c = f.read()) != -1) {
          System.out.print((char)c);
          wd = (char)c;
          CALL(f2, c);
          }
      f.close();              
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }
    }
}
```